# plot lidR Hull object with geom_sf with a basemap

Tags: r, sf, lidr, ggplot2

So I am trying to create a static map by overlaying the tree canopy hulls (created using crown_metrics function) as hollow polygons with yellow color on a ESRI basemap.

How can I resolve the error? I am open to other methods too which shows a static map of hollow hulls with an outline color on a basemap using `ggplot`.

Error:

```
Error in grDevices::rgb(red = df$val1, green = df$val2, blue = df$val3,  : 
  color intensity NA, not in [0,1]
```

Code:

```
# Map both with a basemap
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(lidR)
library(basemaps)

# First set a basemap
set_defaults(map_service = "esri", map_type = "world_imagery")

# Plot the map with the hulls
# st_transform the polygons to the same CRS as that of the basemap
ext = st_transform(Dalponte.Hulls, crs = st_crs(3857))
ggplot() +
basemap_gglayer(ext) +
geom_sf(data = ext$geometry, color = "yellow", fill = "transparent") +
coord_sf() +
scale_fill_identity()
```

Comment: I see nothing related to lidR here. The question is *how to plot a sf object on a map with ggplot* or something like that.

Comment: @JRR sorry I thought the issue might have happened because I might not have used the `crown_metrics` object `Dalponte.Hulls` properly in `ggplot`. I mean can I straight up use `Dalponte.Hulls` in `ggplot` or do I need to do a conversion/extract subset or something first to `sf_object` for plotting via `ggplot`?

Comment: The hulls you get is a standard sf object. You should be able to plot it with anything that can plot sf object. I myself never used ggplot and basemap for that. Your code works on my machine but the background is partially doawloaded.